# Android AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I'm reading a database that has encrypted data. I can read an decrypt the contents but I can't decrypt something that I encrypt. The result are different:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
SecretKey skey = new SecretKeySpec(key, 0, key.length, "AES");
```

Here is how I decrypt the string:

```
public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    byte[] result = new byte[0];                                                                                                    
    try {                                                                                                                           
        cipher.init(DECRYPT_MODE, skey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));                                                                   

        InflaterInputStream inflaterStream = new InflaterInputStream(
            new CipherInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), cipher));
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(inflaterStream);                                                                                 
    } catch (Exception e) {                                                                                                         
        e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                        
        return result;                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                               
}
```

And here is how I encrypt the string:

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data) {                                                                                                                         
    try {                                                                                                                          
        cipher.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));                                                                  
        DeflaterInputStream deflaterInput = new DeflaterInputStream(
            new CipherInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), cipher));

        return IOUtils.toByteArray(deflaterInput);                                                                                 
    } catch (Exception e) {                                                                                                        
        e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                       
        return new byte[0];                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                              
}
```

The error that I get is this:

```
W/System.err: java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check
W/System.err:     at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:170)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2146)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2102)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2123)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2078)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:721)
```

Comment: The error "java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check" has nothing to do with encryption/decryption. It says the Java  zip utility doesn't think its a valid Zip file. May be the file is compressed using some other algorithm , say tar or gzip , and you might have to use the correspondig Java utitlity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nesting of streams on encryption is not correct. On encryption it should be

```
new CipherInputStream(new DeflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data)), cipher);
```

On decryption it should be

```
new InflaterInputStream(new CipherInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), cipher));
```

which is how you had it and is correct.

Comment: You are a savior!